# $T$ selfadjoint with nonnegative spectrum implies $T=S^2$ for some selfadjoint $S$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have question regarding the following problem: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ a bounded linear operator from $H$ to $H$. If we assume that $T$ is selfadjoint with spectrum in $[0,\infty)$ can we conclude that $T=S^2$ for some selfadjoint bounded operator $S$ (I know that this implies that $T$ is positive but I want to show the implication directly)?

I started to define $X = T-aI$ where $a \in (-\infty,0)$. Then $X$ is selfadjoint and invertible but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Quite easy if you can use the spectral theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) How would one show this with the spectral theorem?

Comment: If $T$ is compact, it has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Since it is self-adjoint, its eigenvalues are real, so we can take the positive square root of $\lambda_i.$ Define a new operator $S$ with $Se_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}e_i.$ If instead $T$ is only bounded, we don't have eigenvalues, only a spectral measure. Then define $S=\int \sqrt{\lambda}$ over the spectrum.

Comment: So if we just assume that $T$ is selfadjoint with positive spectrum then we have to argue with the spectral measure?

Comment: There are different ways to do the spectral theorem, some which don't require you to use spectral measure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **yes**. The Theorem on page 265 in Frigyes Riesz and Béla Sz.-Nagy's *Functional Analysis* (Dover paperback 1990) states:

> Every positive symmetric transformation $A$ possesses a positive symmetric square root, and only one, which we denote by $A^{1/2}$. It can be represented as the limit (in the strong sense) of a sequence of polynomials in $A$, and consequently is permutable with all transformations which are permutable with $A$.

What I like about their proof is that it is *constructive*, there is no compactness assumption, it works in *real* or complex Hilbert space and does not use the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize what I said in the comments.

If your self-adjoint operator $T$ is on a finite dimensional space, or otherwise is a compact operator, then [the spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) for compact operators says it has eigenvalues, real eigenvalues due to self-adjointness. And non-negative by hypothesis. Then we may define $S\colon e_i\mapsto \sqrt{\lambda_i}e_i,$ and we will have $S^2=T.$

If $T$ is assumed to be bounded, but not compact, then we are not guaranteed to have eigenvalues, but we still have a complete spectral decomposition. In this case the spectral theorem can take a few forms, in terms of spectral measure, projection-valued measure, and a multiplication operator.

In terms of the projection-valued measure, if we have $T=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE_\lambda$, we may construct $S=\int_{\sigma(T)}\sqrt{\lambda}\,dE_\lambda$ as our square root.

This is the general method by which you can apply any continuous function to an operator, via the [Borel functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus).